# http to https retaining clean urls

Tags: ajax, .htaccess, ssl

I have a site that uses clean URLs and it has a SSL certificate - not used so far. I now need to switch to https so have been looking at modifying the .htaccess file. I have found lots of articles that say how easy it is with

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI}
```

So I put that into my existing .htaccess file, very concerned that the condition in front of all the rules would mess up clean URLs for any user-set calls to https. But I couldn't see how to fit it in afterwards because the rules have an [L] to satisfy other needs.

Needless to say, the file broke the site entirely so it stays on http until I can sort this out. Also I am concerned about css and Ajax calls being messed up.

This is the faulty code:

```
AddType text/x-component .htc
Options +FollowSymLinks
rewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI}
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9-z\-]+)/([a-zA-Z0-9-z\-]+)/([a-zA-Z0-9-z\-]+)/([a-zA-Z0-9-z\-]+)/?$ index.php?page=$1&var1=$2&var2=$3&var3=$4 [L]  
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9-z\-]+)/([a-zA-Z0-9-z\-]+)/([a-zA-Z0-9-z\-]+)/?$ index.php?page=$1&var1=$2&var2=$3 [L]  
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9-z\-]+)/([a-zA-Z0-9-z\-]+)/?$ index.php?page=$1&var1=$2 [L]  
RewriteRule ^([a-z0-9-]+)$ index.php?page=$1  [L]
```

If I did the https part in httpf.conf would that also mess up the site?

Comment: What errors are you getting?

Comment: You are close.  If you add an `[L]` flag to the https:// rewriterule, it should work.

Comment: anubhava - The problem was an Internal Server Error though with the original file a manually entered https works OK. Miah- Wouldn't the [L] just mean the rest - (the clean urls) were ignored as it would mark it as the last rule. Also if the condition is present and the incoming url is already https, it would also mean the clean url rules would be by-passed